# How to bound in on startActivity() requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, runtime-error, fatal-error

Android's bug reporting tool tells me that I have 60 different crashes from 60 different places under the error:

> "Fatal Exception android.util.AndroidRuntimeException Calling
>   startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Also, I send messages back to the Main activity this way from the Service:

```
   public static class ClickHandler extends Handler {
            private final WeakReference<Main> wMain;

            public ClickHandler(Main main) {
                super();
                this.wMain = new WeakReference<Main>(main);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
```

I have never personally reproduced this crash.

I have 3 services that run, but none of them call "startActivity".

The 3 services do send messages back to the Main Activity, and it is conceivable that the services run while the Main Activity is in the background.

How can I begin to bound in on the cause of these multitude of crashes?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't indirectly calling startActivity?  How are you sending the data to the main activity?  Sending data shouldn't attempt to start a new activity, but we don't really know what you're doing.

Comment: I do refer to the Main activity through a hardcoded reference inside the service. this is probably bad eh? (updated question, please see)

Comment: Kinda bad and hacky, can you post the snippet on which the exception occurs? Is the service start as STICKY? From docs: `If the application is running in the background and needs the user's attention, the application should create a notificaiton that allows the user to respond at his or her convenience.`

Comment: @hunterp ~ You said "I do refer to the Main activity through a hardcoded reference inside the service." Please paste the code, which corresponds to the statement, so we can see.

Comment: Can you show us your handlerMessage function and how do you send the message back to the activity from your service ?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you really haven't provide sufficient information to allow us to figure this out.  My bet is this: Just because Main (an Activity, I'm guessing) hasn't been GCed, doesn't mean it is valid.  I bet you are calling some method on it, after it has been destroyed.

Comment: are you calling getApplicationContext().startActivity ?

Comment: Can you pinpoint the exact place where startActivity() is called and causing the crash? Would you consider registering a BroadcastReceiver in your main activity and communicate trough it, instead of Handler?

Comment: Please post an actual stack trace with the exception. Just pick one from the 60 different ones :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should look into using a `BroadcastReceiver` to notify your running `Activity` instances from your `Service`. As others have noted, I suspect you're calling `startActivity` somewhere you shouldn't.